# Unexpected Cloud Function Deployment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a few Google Cloud Functions, which I last updated March 7th. However, I just checked the developer console, and each function has the "Last Deployed" column as March 15th, 05:40 AM (GMT). (Please ignore the top row, as I just re-deployed to that function).

[image: A screenshot of my Cloud Functions overview]

The functions are all working as expected. However, I definitely did not deploy to these functions at this time. I also cannot see any reference to this deployment in my Google Cloud Console logs. Is there any way of checking the source of these deployments? I would like to confirm if I don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Nothing magics! Have a look to audit logs

Comment: This is my mentality too! But there are no related logs in the logging explorer for the timestamp above (+/- 12h). I have also checked for logs via the CLI tool, but still no luck. One note: while I am getting logs on my project (e.g. for container startup, builds I initiated, etc...), I noticed that, in Cloud Console>IAM&Admin>Audit Logs, "Admin Read", "Data Read" and "Data Write" are set to disabled for all services. Do I need to change this?

Comment: Normally, you should be able to see this in the audit logs (dashboard -> activity (upper left corner)). If the mystery persists, ask the Google support.

Comment: No luck there either unfortunately. I will get in touch with Google support, and if they answer my question I'll update this post for traceability for others.